# load next data using content query web part

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I am using CQWP to display some items from a custom list. So far it is working fine, but now I would like to add a button where the user can click to load the next batch of data. Like a sort of paging but showing all items in the same page.

So, the example will be like this:

```
1) on page load I show 3 items (I need to add a button)
2) On button click the next 3 items are loaded (total items shown so far 6)
3) Further load the next data till there are no more items to show
```

I have some xslt basics, but I am not sure how to accomplish this task.
anyone can help with some code or suggestions?

Comment: You need to get all item from CQWP and then apply slider to display all items one by one.

Comment: Suppose that there are more than 100 items in the list to show in content query web part. That will hit the performance if I load them all at once.

Comment: CQWP will load all item when your XSLT main file execute in system. You can load any item run time or dynamically in CQWP.